# How do I set session variables in a custom php file in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In a subpage on my drupal site I have a form. I'd like the form to post to a simple process.php file, that takes the form data and then sets a $_SESSION variable and returns the user to the original page.

Currently the process.php file is not seeing the $_SESSION vars set in standard drupal pages and viceversa, drupal pages don't see the $_SESSION vars set in the process.php file, they act as if they are on completely different sites. What am i missing?

Comment: I also had problems with sessions and switched to cookies and that worked well. Is it an option for you to use cookies instead?

Comment: Please provide more details.
How did you included process.php? Why you did it at all? Drupal have bunch of way to do implement it.

By the way: process.php is a bad name for file name.

Comment: @MilanG I know cookies might be an option, it just didn't feel right using that... it would really just be avoiding the problem altogether.

Comment: @CornelAndreev process.php was just an example filename. I wasn't "including" the file anywhere. I am doing a very simple post, from a form on a page, to that process.php file and in that file I wanted something like this to work: `<?php $_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo']; ?> ` and then return to the original page.

Comment: What I ended up learning is that I needed to create a module and use that to work with the data in my form and set the session vars I wanted. So, that's the answer, build a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research it looks like the only way to set session variables and run your own php code is to create a module.

I've looked at the Drupal.org tutorial here:
https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules
and this one here:
http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/04/29/drupal-7-how-create-module-part-1

Lastly, I'd also recommend looking at existing modules and learning from those as well.